# GridView with edit feature in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

How to create editable GridView like the one provided in the link below:
http://demo2.mixerp.org:8080/Sales/DirectSales.aspx

In this link, once, you select the item, corresponding details are filled. After that, if you click "Add" button, new row is created.

How is this done ?

Comment: use telerik grid instead of <asp:gridview>

Comment: telerik is paid one :-(

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your data to grid view - refer link below..

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1619/how-to-perform-edit-update-and-delete-operation-in-gridview